# Why is it more efficient to create a small array, and then expand it, rather than to create an array entirely from a large list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, performance

Found the following code in a book but couldn't get the complete explanation.

```
x = array('d', [0] * 1000000)
x = array('d', [0]) * 1000000
```

The python code in the first case is creating an array of 1000000 lengths while in the 2nd part is creating a single size array and multiplying the size by the same factor.
The code in the 2nd case is 100 times faster than the first case.

What is the exact reason for the speed difference? How does python implementation of arrays play a role?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Python `list` stores Python objects, but an `array.array` object stores raw C data types.

The first line requires individually processing every object in `[0] * 1000000`, following pointers and performing type checking and dynamic dispatch and reference counting and all that a million times to process every element and convert its data to a raw C double. Every element happens to be the same, but the `array` constructor doesn't know that. There's also the expense of building and cleaning up the million-element list.

The second line is way simpler. Python can just `memcpy` the array's contents a million times.

Comment: But the memcpy function must take the time of dynamically allocating new pointer, copying data into new memory cell in the 2nd line as well.

Comment: @AnshulJain: No it doesn't. memcpy doesn't allocate. Perhaps you're under the impression that `array.array` arrays store Python objects?

Comment: @AnshulJain Could you benchmark it with array('d', itertools.repeat(0,1000000 ))? That should at least skip building the temporary list.